# How to increase left padding in Droidparts ClearableEditText

Tags: android, droidparts

Is there a way to increase the padding in XML code to the left so that the user can comfortably move the cursor at the end of a very long sentence?

[image: screenshot of ClearableEditText default icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the padding can be specified like this:

```
android:drawablePadding="12dp"
```

I'll add this info to the guide.

Comment: Thanks! Great library btw. Hats off to you.